# Is this generating function correct?

Tags: sequences-and-series, generating-functions, geometric-series

I haven't learned how to calculate generating functions, but I know it has to do with reciprocal functions being equal to regular polynomials, which reminds me of geometric series. I decided to make a generating function problem up so I could solve it. So, is the bottom generating function here correct?:$$\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}=1+x-x^2+x^3-...=1+\sum_{k\ge0}(-1)^kx^{k+1}$$I did this by factoring to get the ratio $x(1-x)$, substituted it into the infinite geometric series formula, expanded the binomials, and simplified.

Comment: $x^2-x+1 \not = x(1-x)$

Comment: @Henry but $1-x(1-x)=x^2-x+1$

Comment: @SassatelliGiulio This is different. Look at the O.P. Maybe I am wrong since I haven't done generating functions before.

Comment: @KamalSaleh So you have $\frac{1}{x^2-x+1}=\frac{1}{1-x(1-x)}$.  That will not give you $1+x-x^2+x^3-\cdots$ though it might give you $1+x(1-x)+(x(1-x))^2+(x(1-x))^3+\cdots$.  I doubt that is the easiest way to do this

Comment: @Henry after that expand it out to get $1+x-x^2+x^3-x^4+...$ ( if you take a few terms the last one after expanding might have a coefficient that isn't $1$, but as you add more terms that coefficient disappears).

Comment: @KamalSaleh Expanding, I get $1 +x-x^2 +x^2 -2x^3 + x^4 +x^3-3x^4+3x^5-x^6 + \cdots   $ 
 so $1+x-x^3-\cdots$ which is not what you have with $1+x-x^2+x^3-\cdots$: spot the zero coefficient of $x^2$ and the negative coefficient of $x^3$

Comment: Do a partial fraction decomposition over complex numbers.

Comment: Are you strictly talking about *ordinary* generating functions? Or are you also interested in the [exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Exponential_generating_function_(EGF)) variety?

Comment: You could convert to a geometric sum immediately, provided $|x^2-x|<1$:$$\frac1{x^2-x+1}=\frac1{1-(x-x^2)}=\sum_{n\ge0}(-1)^n(x-x^2)^n$$but this is not a proper (ordinary) generating function. Also, $x^2-x+1=\frac{x^3+1}{x+1}$ and you can readily convert its reciprocal to a geometric sum.